# Correlation of uniform variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, correlation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, $X,Y \sim unif(0,1)$. Let $U = \min \{X,Y\}$ and $V = \max\{X,Y\}$. Find the correlation coefficient of $U$ and $V$.

I think we can assume that $U = X$ and $V = Y$ because they both have the same distribution. Further, $E[U] = E[V] = 1/2$ and $Var(U) = Var(V) = 1/12$. Next is $E[UV]$ and this is where I am stuck, because I can't solve this $E[UV] = \int_{}^{}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}^{}uvf(u,v)dudv$. I think I can substitute $f(u,v)$ with $1$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: $U$ and $X$ do not have the same distribution. $P(U\geq s) = P(X\geq s)P(Y\geq s) = (1-s)^2$. Also you have not properly defined $V$.

Comment: Then could you please tell me how to find E(U)?

Comment: Well $F(s)=P(U\leq s)$, the cdf, you could differentiate that and get a density. Or maybe you remember that for a non-negative random variable $U$, $E[U]=\int_0^\infty (1-F(s))ds$

Comment: $U$ and $V$ are not independent, as $U<V$ !

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2146136/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has several nice shortcuts.

For the first term, you can note that $UV=XY$. This is because one or the other of $X,Y$ is the smaller one and the other is the larger, and multiplication doesn't care what order they come in. So since $ X, Y $ are independent, $ E [UV]= E [X] E [Y] = 1/4$.

We can use a similar trick to calculate $E[U]$ and $E[V]$. Let's think about $U$. We first consider $X=x$. Now with probability $1-x$, $Y>x$, in which case $U=x$. With probability $x$, $Y \leq x$, in which case $U$ is uniform on $[0,x]$. I'll write $U_x$ for a uniform variable on $[0,x]$. Now linearity of expectation tells us that:

$$E[U|X=x]=x (1-x) + x E[U_x]=x (1-x) + x^2/2$$

Now the total expectation formula gives:

$$E[U]=\int_0^1 E[U|X=x] f_X(x) dx = \int_0^1 (x (1-x) + x^2/2) dx.$$

The situation is similar to calculate $E[V]$, $E[U^2]$, and $E[V]^2$, then you can just combine everything to get the correlation coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Let's find the joint distribution.  When $u \leq v$ then 
\begin{align*}
P(U<u,V<v)&=P(\min\{X,Y\}<u,\max\{X,Y\}<v)\\
&=P(X<u,Y<u)+P(X<u,u<Y<v)+P(u<X<v,Y<u)\\
&=P(X<u)P(Y<u)+P(X<u)P(u<Y<v)+P(u<X<v)P(Y<u)\\
&=u^2+2u(v-u)=2uv-u^2 
\end{align*}
When $v<u$ then
\begin{align*}
P(U<u,V<v)&=P(\min\{X,Y\}<u,\max\{X,Y\}<v)=v^2
\end{align*}
Hence $f(u,v)=2$ when $u \leq v$ and $f(u,v)=0$ when $v<u$. Then $f(v)=2v$, $f(u)=2(1-u)$. Then $E[U]=1/3$, $E[U^2]=1/6$, $E[V]=2/3$,  $E[V^2]=1/2$ and 
$$E[UV]=\int_0^1\int_0^{1}uv f(u,v)dudv
=2\int_0^1\int_0^{v}uv dudv
=\int_0^1v^3 dv=\frac{1}{4}$$

Now using this, I get the correlation is $1/2$.

btw. More generally if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have distributions $F_x$ and $F_y$. Then when $u \leq v$,
\begin{align*}
P(U<u,V<v)&=P(\min\{X,Y\}<u,\max\{X,Y\}<v)\\
&=F_x(u)F_y(u)+F_x(u)(F_y(v)-F_y(u))
+F_y(u)(F_x(v)-F_x(u))\\
&=F_x(v)F_y(u)+F_x(u)F_y(v)-F_x(u)F_y(u)
\end{align*}
and when $v<u$,
$$
P(U<u,V<v)=P(\min\{X,Y\}<u,\max\{X,Y\}<v)=F_x(v)F_y(v)
$$
so $f(v,u)=f_x(v)f_y(u)+f_x(u)f_y(v)$ when $u \leq v$ and $f(v,u)=0$ when $v<u$. Using this you can calculate $E[g(U,V)]$ for any function $g$.

Comment: The PDF of (U,V) is wrong and not useful. The value of E(UV) is wrong.

Comment: That value of $E[UV]$ doesn't even make sense, $U \in [0,1]$ and $V \in [0,1]$ so $E[UV] \in [0,1]$...

Comment: @Did PDF is corrected. The PDF is useful to calculate $E[UV]$.

Comment: @Ian You are correct. I made a mistake in the PDF calculation. It's been corrected now.

Comment: @user103828 In general yes, of course, but not in this case. Did you read Ian's answer?

Comment: @Did Yes, I read Ian's answer and I agree that he has some clever shortcuts to get to the solution.

Comment: OK (although I would not describe these remarks as "shortcuts" but rather as pointing to the fundamental structure of the question). But anyway, where does this leave us about the usefulness of the distribution of (U,V) to compute E(UV)?

Comment: I agree that my solution is much more "brute force" and for sure Ian's solution is much better for $E[UV]$ but we then need compute $E[U]$ and $E[V]$ and one way to get there is through the PDF... Ian's method for $E[V]$ and $E[U]$ is arguably easier but also requires some thought while once you have the PDF all expectations are straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check whether your answer is correct using a computer algebra system. In this instance, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard Uniform random variables, their joint pdf, say $f(x,y)$ is:

```
f = 1;   domain[f] = {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}};
```

Then, you seek:

```
Corr[{Min[x, y], Max[x, y]}, f]
```

$\frac12$

where I am using here the `Corr` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. As disclosure, I should perhaps add that I am one of the authors.

The expectation you are having trouble with is $E[U V]$:

```
Expect[Min[x, y] Max[x, y], f]
```

$\frac14$

Also, your calculation $E[U] = E[V] = 1/2$ is plainly wrong:  this should be obvious since $E[X] = \frac12$, so $E[min[X,Y]]$ must be less than $\frac12$.