# Find $\text{Cov}[X,Y]$, given $X = \text{min}(U,V )$ and $Y = \text{max}(U,V )$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

> Let $U$ and $V$ be independent and $\text{unif}[0,1]$ and let $X =
>  \text{min}(U,V)$ and $Y = \text{max}(U,V)$. Find $\text{Cov}[X,Y]$ and
>   comment on its sign.

I know that $\text{Cov}[X,Y]=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y],$ so I need both of the mean-terms. Letting $g(X,Y)=XY$ I get

$$E[XY]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y) \ dxdy=...?$$

What I don't understand is the min and max functions, I know what they mean but not how to do algebra with them. How do I find the bounds of my integrals?

Am I correct to say that since $U,V\sim\text{Unif}[0,1]$ and independent, then the variables $X$ and $Y$ are also $\sim\text{Unif}[0,1]$ and independent? If this is true, then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)=1\cdot 1=1$ and $E(X)=E(Y)=\frac{1}{2}.$ So

$$E(XY)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}xy\ dxdy=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Finally: $$\text{Cov}[X,Y]=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}=0.$$

This means that $X$ and $Y$ is independent. But this does feel circular because I assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and then I prove what I'm assuming.

Comment: In general, zero covariance means uncorrelated;not necessarily independent. But $X$ and $Y$ are never independent to begin with , since $Y>X$ with probability one. One possible way is to find the joint density of $(X,Y)$ and then find the covariance.

Comment: I think I've solved this problem with Arnaldo's method. But I'm much interested in finding the joint pdf of $(X,Y).$ Can you show me how this is done?

Comment: By finding the joint cdf and differentiating to get the joint density, as usual. It has been surely derived here before.

Comment: The joint of the order statistic is not that hard to write - you just need to normalize by the permutation (i.e. divided by $2!$) and then limit the support to something like $0 < x  < y < 1$. Everything else would be the same as the joint pdf of un-ordered statistics.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2146136/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I got an answer of $Cov(X,Y) > 0$...  Am I right or wrong?

First of all, $X,Y$ are *not* independent, because as @StubbornAtom pointed out, $P(Y>X) = 1$.  Alternatively, consider that $P(X>{1\over 2}) = P(U>{1\over 2}, V>{1\over 2}) = {1\over 4}$ but $P(X > {1\over 2} | Y < {1\over 2}) = 0$, directly demonstrating dependence.

So $Cov(X,Y)$ is not trivially zero.  To find its value:

- $U, V$ are $\text{Unif}[0,1] \Rightarrow E[U] = E[V] = {1 \over 2}$.
- $U,V$ are independent $\Rightarrow E[UV] = E[U]E[V] = {1 \over 4}$.
- Regardless of $U > V$ or $U < V$, we have $UV = XY$ always.  So $E[XY] = E[UV] = {1 \over 4}$.
- From integration (not shown here), $E[Y] = {2\over 3}, E[X] = {1\over 3}$.

  - Disclaimer: I remember doing this integration in the past, but I did not recheck it today.
- $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = {1\over 4} - {1\over 3}{2\over 3} = {1\over 36} \neq 0$.

Comment: This answer is correct. I did not bother looking at the answers yesterday, became a bit late. To carry out those integrations, one needs to find the pdf's of $X$ and $Y$. How do I do this without knowing their distribution?

Comment: I really don't understand why $P(Y>a)=P(U>a)P(V>a)$? In the page you linked to, they use $P(Y<a),$ but you go the reverse?

Comment: haha, sorry, my older comment (now deleted) got them reversed!  $Y = \max(U,V)$ so $Y<a$ iff $U<a$ and $V<a$, i.e. $P(Y<a) = P(U<a)P(U<a)$.  From this you can do the integrals yourself or you can reference: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18433/how-do-you-calculate-the-probability-density-function-of-the-maximum-of-a-sample

Comment: So if we let $a=y$, we get that $$F_Y(y)=P(Y< y)=P(U<y)P(V<y)=\int_0^y f_U(y) \ dy\cdot \int_0^y f_V(y) \ dy = y^2,$$ since $f_U(y)=f_V(y) = 1.$ Differentiating we get $f_Y(y)=2y,$ so $$E[Y]=\int_0^1y f_Y(y) \ dy = \frac{2}{3}.$$ Is this correct?

Comment: yes except for a typo: $f_Y(y) = 2y$, not $2a$.

Comment: For $X$ we have that $X > x$ iff $U>x$ and $V>x$, so by the same analogy as above but with reversed inequality sign, we get $$F_X(x)=P(X>x)=P(U>x)P(V>x)=\left(1-\int_0^xf_U(x) \ dx \right)\left(1-\int_0^xf_V(x) \ dx \right)=(1-x)^2.$$ Differentiating we get $f_X(x)=2(x-1).$ Finally $$E[X]=2\int_0^1xf_X(x) \ dx=-\frac{1}{3}.$$ Can you see why my sign is reversed?

Comment: $P(X>x) = (1-x)^2$, but the CDF is defined as $F_X(x) = P(X < x) = 1 - (1 - x)^2$ etc.

Comment: My humble personage, bows before your grandeur. Thank you.