# Let $U = \min\{X,Y\}$ and $V = \max\{X,Y\}$. Find $\textbf{E}(U)$, and hence calculate $\textbf{Cov}(U,V)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance, expected-value

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables each having the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Let $U = \min\{X,Y\}$ and $V = \max\{X,Y\}$. Find $\textbf{E}(U)$, and hence calculate $\textbf{Cov}(U,V)$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

In the first place, let us determine the distribution of $U$ and $V$:

\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(U\leq u) & = \textbf{P}(\min\{X,Y\}\leq u) = 1 - \textbf{P}(\min\{X,Y\} > u)\\\\
& = 1 - \textbf{P}(X > u,Y > u) = 1 - \textbf{P}(X > u)\textbf{P}(Y > u)\\\\
& = 1 - (1 - F(u))(1 - F(u)) = F(u)(2 - F(u)) \Rightarrow\\\\
f_{U}(u) & = 2f(u) - 2f(u)F(u) = 2f(u)(1-F(u))
\end{align*}

Analogously, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(V\leq v) & = \textbf{P}(\max\{X,Y\}\leq v) = \textbf{P}(X\leq v, Y\leq v)\\\\
& = \textbf{P}(X\leq v)\textbf{P}(Y\leq v) = F(v)^{2}\Rightarrow\\\\
f_{V}(v) & = 2F(v)f(v) 
\end{align*}

where
\begin{cases}
f(x) = 1\quad\text{for}\quad 0 \leq x \leq 1\\\\
F(x) = x\quad\text{for}\quad 0 \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}

Which means that $f_{U}(u) = 2(1-u)$ and $f_{V}(v) = 2v$. Based on this, it is routine to calculate $\textbf{E}(U)$ and $\textbf{Cov}(U,V)$ according to
\begin{cases}
\textbf{E}(U) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}uf_{U}(u)\mathrm{d}u\\\\
\textbf{Cov}(U,V) = \textbf{E}(UV) - \textbf{E}(U)\textbf{E}(V)
\end{cases}

In the first place, I'd be grateful if someone could double-check my results. Thenceforth, I'd like to know if there is another approach to the same problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Based on this, it is routine to calculate ... Cov(U,V)=E(UV)−E(U)E(V)" Hmmm... How do you deduce E(UV) from the PDFs of U and V? "I'd be grateful if someone could double-check my results" Where are "your results" for E(U) and for Cov(U,V)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2146136/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a direct way:

\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}U &=\mathsf{E}U1\{X\le Y\}+\mathsf{E}U1\{X> Y\} \\
&=\int_0^1\int_x^1 x\, dydx+\int_0^1\int_0^x y\, dydx=\frac{1}{3}.
\end{align}

---

To calculate the expectation of $UV$, notice that $UV=XY$. Therefore, $\mathsf{E}UV=\mathsf{E}X\mathsf{E}Y=1/4.$