# Covariance of max and min of two uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, covariance

Let X, Y be two independent random variables following a uniform distribution in the interval (0,1). Let U=Min(X,Y), and V=Max(X,Y). How do I find the Covariance(V,U)?
Since X and Y are i.i.d., I guess $F_U(u)= 2F_x(u)-F_x^2(u)$, thus E(U)=1/3;
on the other hand, I should have $F_V(v)=F_x^2(v)$, with E(V)=2/3.
How do I find the joint distribution $F_{UV}(u,v)$ and thus E(UV)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2146136/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to find joint distribution. Note that $UV=XY$, so $$\mathbb E(UV)=\mathbb E(XY)=\mathbb E(X)\mathbb E(Y)=\frac14.$$

Comment: You're right, I didn't mind about, thanks. Could you also tell me if my previous steps are right, please?

Comment: Yes, the expectations of $U$ and $V$ are $1/3$ and $2/3$.

Comment: @NCh Oddly, the result $1/36$ is positive, although we could have awaited a negative covariance because in this case if "min" is small, "max" is big (and the reverse); Is there an explanation ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Vice versa: the larger the minimum, the greater the maximum since max is greater than min.

Comment: @NCh I realize where my error was : I was in fact reasoning intuitively to normalized versions RV : (X/(X+Y), Y/(X+Y))